# searchText.indexOf is not a function in Protractor 5.3.0

Tags: protractor

We recently upgraded from Protractor 4.0.14 to 5.3.0 and are encountering an error. Our test is doing something like:

```
element.all(by.css('some locator')).all(by.cssContainingText('some locator', 'some description'));
```

It passes fine with protractor 4.0.14, but with 5.3.0, I'm getting this error:

> - Failed: unknown error: searchText.indexOf is not a function
>         (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.146)

Did something change with the latest version of protractor that is causing this?

Comment: I don't actually see a `getText()` call? It looks like you are just returning all elements that match. In which case, `searchText` is not a string but an `ElementArrayFinder` instead. Are you sure you posted the correct code snippet?

Comment: @tehbeardedone you are correct, I'm not making a getText() call.  It seems that the error is occurring in the call to cssContainingText().

Comment: Interesting. Where is `searchText` coming from then? I don't see it in your snippet?

Comment: I suspect the possibility to use `element.all().all()`, from my point,  you can only use `element.all()`, can't chain `all()` after another `all()`

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/angular/protractor/commits/master/lib/locators.ts

It looks like there was some change to the `cssContainingText` locator to allow for a regex. But I don't see `indexOf` in that file.

Here's the commit
https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/4532

And I see that it also touches `clientSideScripts.ts` https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/clientsidescripts.js

In `functions.findByCssContainingText` it makes a reference to `searchText.indexOf('__REGEXP__')` and it looks like it might be able to encounter an error condition similar to yours if `searchText` is undefined.

Are using `by.cssContainingText('someSelector')` without a second argument? or where your second argument might be coming in as null/undefined (and not an empty string)?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was simply that I wasn't passing a string argument to `cssContainingText`, but rather a number value. The fix was simply to convert it to a string (add `+''`) e.g.

```
by.cssContainingText('css selector', 123 + ''))
```

In previous versions this worked fine due to Javascript's dynamic typing, but when regex support was added (as mentioned in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50184680/690188)) [the code](https://github.com/joeheyming/protractor/blob/66693fc3099a26cf7f36a4e5559c4bc6ecfccdc6/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L687) now started calling the `indexOf` function on the argument which will only work on strings.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that if I reference a descriptor (in my case regex) from inside another object outside of the one containing the selector I got this error as well. Basically passing it an index instead of a direct reference breaks it. Like so....

```
element.all(by.css('some locator')).all(by.cssContainingText('some locator', CONSTANTS.regexPatterns.someDescriptionRegex)
```

A more direct reference within 'this' works fine though...

```
someDescriptionRegex: {get function() { return new RegExp(...) }},

element.all(by.css('some locator')).all(by.cssContainingText('some locator', this.someDescriptionRegex)
```

Hope this helps.